# Mapped drives not found by windows service, despite logging in as correct account

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

Windows 10 Pro

Version 1709 OS

Build 16299.666

I have a service which would like to access network drive `U:/public/blah.txt`.  Running it as a normal user with the command prompt works, running it as a service does not.

If go to `services.msc -> servicename -> properties -> Log On -> This account` and use `MYDOMAIN/MYUSER` and the correct password and restart, it still does not work, and produces the same error message.  This is the account which can successfully run the program from the command prompt.

It's a golang executable running inside a [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) service and the actual error message is `Error opening file U:\public\blah.txt: The system cannot find the path specified`.

This program used to work as a service on a different computer, it's even accessing the same drive. the only difference I can see is that the account I'm using now is a domain account, whereas before it was a local user.

Why isn't my service seeing the drive mappings, if it is successfully logged in as the user who has them?

Comment: Is the service mapping the drive before it attempts to access it? Alternately, can you access the file using a UNC path instead of a mapped drive?

Comment: How is the drive being mapped? If the drive isn’t set to persist then it won’t be available in a service running as that user. In addition, if the domain account is a local admin you may have the UAC issue described here: http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/developer/mapped_drives_not_available.htm in any case trying to access a mapped drive from a service is horrible, terrible, no good programming. Access the data directly via it’s UNC path.

Comment: The drive is already mapped by the user many reboots ago.  The UNC path works on both, that was it.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having the service access the data via a mapped drive, use a UNC path name instead.

There are a variety of ways a drive can be mapped when a user profile is loaded. Not all of them are triggered when a *service* logs on using a particular account. For this reason, UNC paths are more reliable than mapped drives.